# C++: Make a text adventure go screen by screen?

Tags: c++, text, formatting

I'm getting to a point in my programming lessons where I'm required to make a text adventure video game, I've gotten through the hardest part, figuring out the storyline and objective.

However, how i would want this game to go if i was playing it would be to do each step page by page. Is there a way to do this on a terminal/console in c++ without some sort of creative use of `\n` or something? This could also be easier if those pages were equated to a value within a variable.

Comment: `system("cls")` (Windows) or `system("clear")` (*unix) maybe?

Comment: yeah that's fair, i knew that i already understood a way to do it but it's been a while, and i was just thinking about how i could use `cls` as an answer, my apology feel free to delete this thread.